# Is there an easy way to tell what group a unit is part of?

Tags: rebuild-the-universe

Under the Achievements tab, there are quite a few that are into "X of each Y unit", for example "5 of each quantum unit".  These give a bonus of cheaper unlocks, but I'm not sure which units belong to which group.

Is there some kind of simple way to determine what group a specific unit falls into?

Comment: [This source js](http://rebuildtheuniverse.com/Calculs2.js) has the information about which units fall under which achievement, but they are not named, instead they are counted from 0 upwards. Maybe someone not lazy can make a list or something...  
`achiQuantum` is the first function you should be looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That guy made an add-on for it.

https://www.reddit.com/r/rebuildtheuniverse/comments/2ll9am/spacemonster_javascript_addon_for_rebuild_the/

Answer (score 1):

From now on, it is default in the game itself. For example:

[image: Picture of the game]